# OCR : Replace recognized text with its translation like google translate

Tags: android, opencv, firebase-mlkit

I am working on an OCR project. I using Firebase ML Kit for Optical character recognition. I have to replace the text with its translation in different language over the captured image. For that i need to erase the text from the original image before drawing translated text over it.

[image: Recognized]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/img/29b56550af620fa1.png))</sub>

I have tried to extract the possible background color and text color from the detected co-ordinate of the text. Its almost success. But the problem is, the background will became static color.

https://superuser.com/questions/1359257/how-to-use-ffmpeg-removelogo-filter

I am able to get the exact co-ordinate of the original text in the image. Found delogo filter in FFMPEG for videos. Since the adjacent pixels fill the desired area, would like to try it for Bitmap images in android. Any algorithm/implementation already there for removing logo/watermark/object from a bitmap.

Expecting something like this

[image: Expected]

Comment: I also unable to replace the original text with translated text like Google Translate. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google Translator using Firebase Ml Kit [Example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text)

After get FirebaseVisionDocumentText you can use google Translate API

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am able to  detect text and translate it. My problem is to replace the original text with the translated text on the captured image. Like the expected image i shown in the question. For that, i have to erase the original text from the image first. Any help is appreciated :). Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2OfQdYrHRs

Comment: What do you mean by that background will become static color? If you have simple background cases like in figure1 or examples in the video. then just inpainting the background with mask and placing test above it should work. Can you share the current result? and specify what kind of improvement you want?

Comment: @Gravita Tiwari [captured image](https://doc-0o-6s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/5snorteghq573hist61rpes19gkok4ig/epkcau83ajv46v2h0g74scoh7nv6ropu/1556280000000/01757174328872047360/01757174328872047360/1QdZulto5ppRNQAmq3KQSmA6HgJAiWNYI) [Translated image](https://doc-04-6s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/5snorteghq573hist61rpes19gkok4ig/dv9vbgm51b3vu1diiq3b268sikdc0mg7/1556280000000/01757174328872047360/01757174328872047360/1QGsLZil0a_bSIbokNSuMUITR3aBfsCGZ)

Comment: @CleanCoder Can you post some code how you are able to detect text and translate it.